# What is the role of "ever" here?

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain me what is the role and meaning of "ever" in this sentence?
"Before the present author **ever** became associated with ..."

Comment: It's called an ***intensifier***. Syntactically speaking it's  *emphasising* the associated verb ***became associated***. If you find it difficult to see what that actually means in this exact context, think of the emphasis as attaching to the word ***before*** instead. So it means ***Long** before [I met so-and-so]*.

Comment: Note that you'll often see ***ever*** (and ***even***, near-synonymous in context) used in proximity to ***before*** like this. *Even before I met her I liked her.* More "poetically", *Before ever I saw her face, I could imagine it*.

Comment: Note that my first example above could "just about" be reversed to *Before even I met her...* (more naturally, *Before I even met her...*), but you can't reverse the first first two words of the second example like that (moving ***ever*** to be after the subject and closer to the verb, as *Before I ever saw her face...* is okay, though).

Answer (score 1):

It is simply used for emphasis. The meaning is the same.

The reason that it can be used for emphasis is that it is difficult to find a word to emphasise in the expression, " "Before the present author became associated with ...". It would be possible to emphasise "became" but "became" isn't a strong word. By introducing "ever", we can place a strong vocal emphasis on the word "ever".